# heroku: compound values in config

Tags: heroku, foreman

Our app has some configuration that requires a list.

Is there any prior art for containing lists in the heroku config / exporting arrays through environment variables?

Comment: One of the way to solve this problem is to store the configuration values as comma separated string, then convert it into list after reading from environment.

Comment: @anuragal do you see this commonly done anywhere?

Comment: If you are asking about storing a array/list in heroku config then this is something very new to me, not heard or seen. But storing configuration values comma separated is what we are doing in one of our project.